# Mailchimp popup form javascript character encoding error

Tags: javascript, mailchimp

I have the popup code working and it appears there are no issues, if however i open the subscribe form on my site while having firebug active it says there is an error as follows "The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature."

I looked over the code for a `<meta encoding="uft-8">` tag and found one correctly in the top of the html page. Next I inspected the form itself and noticed this popup contained a `<html>` tag but did not contain a `<meta encoding="utf-8">` I looked into this and the form appears to be generated remotely by mailchimp, this means I cannot edit this and thus cannot fix the error. My next point of call was to contact mailchimp development team but unfortunately to do this you have to pay for mailchimp (which frankly as it is broken according to the javascript error console is an odd demand for a potential fix).

In my js file I have.

```
    // Fill in your MailChimp popup settings below. Note I replaced these fields
    // These can be found in the original popup script from MailChimp.
    var mailchimpConfig = {
        baseUrl: '#####################',
        uuid: '########################',
        lid: '###########'
    };

    // No edits below this line are required
    var chimpPopupLoader = document.createElement("script");
    chimpPopupLoader.src = '//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js';
    chimpPopupLoader.setAttribute('data-dojo-config', 'usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false');

    var chimpPopup = document.createElement("script");
    chimpPopup.appendChild(document.createTextNode('require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function (L) { L.start({"baseUrl": "' + mailchimpConfig.baseUrl + '", "uuid": "' + mailchimpConfig.uuid + '", "lid": "' + mailchimpConfig.lid + '"})});'));


    jQuery(function ($) {
        document.body.appendChild(chimpPopupLoader);
        //Mailchimp Pop
        jQuery('#mailchimp-signup-click').on( 'click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.body.appendChild(chimpPopup);
            document.cookie = 'MCPopupClosed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
            document.cookie = 'MCPopupSubscribed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
        });
        jQuery('#mailchimp-signup-button').on( 'click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.body.appendChild(chimpPopup);
            document.cookie = 'MCPopupClosed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
            document.cookie = 'MCPopupSubscribed=;path=/;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
        });

    });
```

My html contains

```
<div class="newsletter__button">
        <a href="#" id="mailchimp-signup-button">
            Click here            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
```

As I already mentioned the form works, if you click the button the form is loaded and after you fill the fields and submit the contents are sent to the mailchimp server. My issue is My SEO deptment are saying that either the error is removed from the console or we remove the plugin.

My request is either a workaround that injects the meta into the remote content or that the developers at mailchimp can amend the content to include an encoding meta tag if needed.

thanks

ADDITIONAL: After Rup's comment I checked on chrome and IE and indeed this error didn't show on eithers debug console. However FF is a popular browser and as said initially Mailchimp is working so the issue is not functionality but standards compliance. Indeed Google may or may not penalise on this issue but none the less it still shows as an error. The fix is a simple one for the developers to be fair.

Comment: "My next point of call was to contact mailchimp development team but unfortunately to do this you have to pay for mailchimp" - would free contact definitely not filter though? But it'd be worth signing up for a month at $10 to get this fixed. This may also be Firefox-specific too, so e.g. you probably wouldn't see an error on Chrome, so if Google really would count a script warning in a popup against you (and I'd be surprised) then they might not actually see it themselves.

Comment: What “plain text document” is this referring to?

Comment: The plain text document is the form that is injected from the remote mailchimp server. I've verified this is the case by isolating sections of a problem page. without the signup no error, with it this possible encoding issue